# MongDB Database was not created in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code

*Database wasn't created*

**This is my error report**

> state.db is not a function
> TypeError: state.db is not a function
> at Object.module.exports.get (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\config\connection.js:28:18)
> at Object.addProduct (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\helpers\product-helpers.js:8:12)
> at C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\routes\admin.js:51:17
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (C:\Users\sainupangad\Desktop\newproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

**This is my code**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


const state = { db: null }


module.exports.connect = function (done) {
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const dbname = 'shoping'


    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return done(err)
        state.db = data.db(dbname)
        done()
    })
}

module.exports.get = function () {
    return state.db()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at your exported get function:

```
  module.exports.get = function () {
     return state.db()
  }
```

You are calling the state.db but as we can see in your connect function that you already constructed the db instance, so you don't need to call the constructor once again.

What should solve your problem is changing `state.db()` to `state.db`